# problem with inserting data in local storage

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

i got this error
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(no such table: offlineData (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO offlineData (date) VALUES (?)) sql 'INSERT INTO offlineData (date) VALUES (?)' args [4/18/2023])

```
the database file
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
//first create a class
import 'dart:io';

class DatabaseHelper {
  //variables
  static const dbName = 'krishibajarDb.db';
  static const dbVersion = 1;
  static const dbTable = 'offlineData';
  static const columnId = 'id';
  static const columnDate = 'date';
  // static const columnTime = 'time';
  // static const columnPerson = 'person';
  // static const columnCategory = 'category';
  // static const columnSubCategory = 'subCategory';
  // static const columnMinPrice = 'minPrice';
  // static const columnMaxPrice = 'maxPrice';

  //constructor
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper();

  //database initialize
  static Database? _database;
  Future<Database?> get database async {
    _database ??= await initDB();
    return _database;
  }

  initDB() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path =
        join(directory.path, dbName); //it needs path and database name
    return await openDatabase(path, version: dbVersion, onCreate: onCreate);
  }

  //creating onCreate method
  Future onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    db.execute('''
CREATE TABLE $dbTable (
  $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  $columnDate TEXT NOT NULL
 
 
)
''');
  }


//  $columnTime TEXT NOT NULL
//   $columnPerson TEXT NOT NULL
//   $columnCategory TEXT NOT NULL
//   $columnSubCategory TEXT NOT NULL
//   $columnMinPrice TEXT NOT NULL
//   $columnMaxPrice TEXT NOT NULL

  //CRUD methods for the app

  //insert the data
  insertData(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database? db = await instance.database;
    return await db!.insert(dbTable, row);
  }

  //read the data
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryDatabase() async {
    Database? db = await instance.database;
    return db!.query(dbTable);
  }

  //update the database+++++++++
  Future<int> updateData(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database? db = await instance.database;
    int id = row[columnId];
    return await db!
        .update(dbTable, row, where: '$columnId=?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  //delete the database
  Future<int> deleteData(int id) async{
    Database? db=await instance.database;
    return await db!.delete(dbTable,where: '$columnId=?',whereArgs: [id]);
  }
}
```

```
the file where i tried to insert the data from

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:kbajar/database/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:kbajar/models/addprice_model.dart';
import 'package:kbajar/pages/test.dart';

class AddPrice extends StatefulWidget {
  List<int> id = [];
  var time1,date1,user;
  var currentIndex = 0;
  
  AddPrice({
    required this.id,
    required this.time1,
    required this.user,
    required this.date1,
  });

  @override
  State<AddPrice> createState() => _AddPriceState();
}

class _AddPriceState extends State<AddPrice> {
  
  List<String> arrayName = [];

  List<PriceModel> PriceList = [];
  List<TextEditingController> minPriceController = [];
  List<TextEditingController> maxPriceController = [];
  Future<List<PriceModel>> getPrice() async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://krishibajar.p1.gov.np/api/market/product-sub-types/',
        );
    final response = await http.get(url);

    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      for (Map i in data) {
        var apiData = PriceModel.fromJson(i);
        for (int id in widget.id) {
          if (apiData.product == id) {
            PriceList.add(apiData);
            
            for (var i = 0; i < PriceList.length; i++) {
              minPriceController.add(TextEditingController());
              maxPriceController.add(TextEditingController());
            }
          }
        }
      }      
      return PriceList;
    } else {
      return PriceList;
    }
  }

  List<String> getIteminArray() {
    PriceList.forEach((element) {
      arrayName.add(element.name!);
    });

    return arrayName;
  }

  void _removeCard(int index) {
    PriceList.removeAt(index);
    setState(() {});
  }

//  var selectedIndex=-1;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Add price')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                color: const Color.fromARGB(66, 163, 163, 163),
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 110,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children:  [
                    Text(
                      'Date:${widget.date1}',
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Seller:${widget.user}',
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Product time:${widget.time1}',
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
              future: getPrice(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const LinearProgressIndicator();
                } else {
                  return Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: PriceList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            leading: Container(
                              width: 62,
                              // color: Colors.blueGrey,
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 62,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 60,
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      const Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255),
                                  child: Image.network(
                                    PriceList[index].productIcon ??
                                        'https://www.applesfromny.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Cameo_NYAS-ApplesNEW.png',
                                    height: 55,
                                    width: 55,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            title: Text(PriceList[index].name.toString()),
                            subtitle: Container(
                              width: 50,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                    controller: minPriceController[index],
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                        label: Text('Min price'),
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                width: 1,
                                                color: Colors.black))),
                                  )),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                    controller: maxPriceController[index],
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                        label: Text('Max price: '),
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                width: 1,
                                                color: Colors.black))),
                                  )),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            trailing: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  _removeCard(index);
                                },
                                child: const Icon(
                                  Icons.close,
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                )),
                          );
                        }),
                  );
                }
              }),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 45,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
                ),
                onPressed: () async{
                  await DatabaseHelper.instance.insertData({
                    DatabaseHelper.columnDate: widget.date1//date1.toString()
                    // DatabaseHelper.columnCategory:PriceList[selectedIndex].name,
                    // DatabaseHelper.columnPerson: ,
                    // DatabaseHelper.columnTime: ,
                    // DatabaseHelper.columnSubCategory:$date1,
                    // DatabaseHelper.columnMinPrice:minPriceController,
                    // DatabaseHelper.columnMaxPrice:maxPriceController,

                  });
                  var dbquery=await DatabaseHelper.instance.queryDatabase();
                  print(dbquery);


                  // Navigator.push(
                  //     context,
                  //     MaterialPageRoute(
                  //         builder: (context) => Test(
                  //               minPrice: minPriceController,
                  //               maxPrice: maxPriceController,
                  //             )));

                },
                child: const Text(
                  'सुरक्षित गर्नुहोस',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I created a local db and tried to insert a data but i am getting error saying
Exception has occurred.